# Why svn reported no space error?

Tags: svn

I created repository in a very big directory **/usr/local/xu/logs** which has more than **14G**.

But When I committed a folder whose size is **3G**, it reported no space.

```
df -h

/dev/vdb  15G  337M   14G   3% /usr/local/xu/logs
```

My repository is  **/usr/local/xu/logs/svnroot/vensoftware**

I want to know why this happened, how can I resolve it? thanks.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information here. What is the **exact error message**? How do you serve your repository?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know **where** the "no space" is being reported from.

What's probably happening is the location where your server is storing tempfiles is smaller than 3GB, and **that** is why you're running out of space.